# Could not find a declaration file for module, @types/...@latest' is not in the npm registry

Tags: reactjs, npm, pivot-table, npm-install, pivottable.js

I install react-pivottable then when I import this

```
import PivotTableUI from 'react-pivottable';
```

I am gettig this as error as `vscode` warning

```
 Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-pivottable'.
 '.../node_modules/react-pivottable/PivotTableUI.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
 Try `npm install @types/react-pivottable` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) 
 file containing `declare module 'react-pivottable';`ts(7016)
```

Then I  type `npm install @types/react-pivottable`

But at this time I am getting this error as console output

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@types%2freact-pivottable - Not found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  '@types/react-pivottable@latest' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\tphusnua\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-07-28T08_48_48_808Z-debug.log
```

What should I do ? Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another thing that you can do is mentioned in the error :(since you already tried npm install and it did not work)

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-pivottable'.
 '.../node_modules/react-pivottable/PivotTableUI.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
 Try `npm install @types/react-pivottable` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) 
 file containing `declare module 'react-pivottable';`ts(7016)
```

1. create a typings or type folder(name it as you want)
2. have a file created - decalaration.d.ts and in that file write `declare module 'react-pivottable;`
3. in *tsconfig.json* add `"typeRoots": ["./typings","node_modules/@types"]` <- path to your typings folder and also path to types in node_modules so that if types are present in node_modules it will be referred

**Note** : This can also be resolved by adding following property to *tsconfig.json*:

```
"noImplicitAny": false
```

Comment: Hey, @Tejeshree, you are good, I tried your `"noImplicitAny": false` and it worked really fine so far, I had many trouble wiht those module declerations and typings, and find difficult your first suggestion, I need to invest some time to modules later. Thank you and any additional advice is more than welcome. And out of curiosity, how long have you been working on js and this related topics?

Comment: Glad i could help! I am working on js for couple of years now, and these related topics are known due to interest in the subject.